# Discord.py multi word arguments, another option?

Tags: python, arguments, discord.py, args

I know I can use `*args`, I know I can use `*, arg`, and I know I can use quotes around the command to make them read as one argument. The last option seems appealing to be but is there a way to make the bot automatically assume there are quotes around a certain argument to allow multiple words? Maybe allowing as many words as I want until a specific character is used, then it breaks into the next argument? I can't use *args for this because the final argument needs to allow multiple words too. Without reconstructing the command, how can I allow an argument to accept multiple words?

I've seen a bot do this before, but it was in js, so I'm actually thinking it might not be possible but idk.

Comment: Can you explain what are you tried to do more?

Comment: I want to be able to type a command like this: `/name hello my name is --world --land` but doing that is only possible if I type `/name "hello my name is" --world --land`. Basically, I need to be able to use multiple arguments at the end (the world and land are each one filter, separated by `--`). The current parameters are `(self, ctx, nickname, *, filtered)` and I would like the nickname part to allow multiple words without requiring multiple words

Comment: Have you considered using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will let you do that. It will loop through the string, adding each character to a separate string, and if it comes across the specified delimiter, it appends that string to a list. It keeps doing this until it reaches the end of the given string.

```py
def seperArgs(arg,delimeter):
    finalArgs = []
    toAppend = ''
    index = 0
    for i in arg:
        if(i == delimeter):
            finalArgs.append(toAppend.strip())
            toAppend = ''
        else:
            toAppend += i
        if(index == len(arg) - 1):
            finalArgs.append(toAppend.strip())
            toAppend = ''
        index += 1
    return finalArgs

print(seperArgs('hello my name is -world -land','-'))

#should print: ['hello my name is', 'world', 'land']
```